# Compare performance between loop(foreach) and query database mysql with 1000 rows in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to compare performance between loop(foreach) and select data with same condition in more than 1000 rows or bigger. 
Example

> Solution 1

```
$query1 = "select * from table 
            where table.name LIKE 'like-name' 
            and table.age = 1 
            and table.address = 'USA' ";
```

...proccess something database...
then return $results about more than 100 or 1000 rows that i want.

> Solution 2

```
$query2 = "select * from table where table.name LIKE 'like-name' ";
```

...proccess something database...
then $results and i use foreach to filter results like this

```
$results2 = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
  if($result['age'] == 1 && $result['address'] == 'USA') {
    $results2 = $result;
  }
}
return $results2;
```

and then i get result that i want 
So, what solution is performance better? :)

Comment: In general, let MySQL do all the hard work. Probably the most time sonsuming thing would be shipping the results bacl across the network. So the less data you have to move around, the better

Comment: yes. Thank bro. first time, i think solution 2 better :)

Comment: Why ask us? Why not suck it and see?

Comment: If i knew, i would not be ask here, @Strawberry , I have recently learn php for 1.5 years without support. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly, the first solution will be faster just because it reduces rows count that will be transferred from DB to PHP. Moreover if there is will be an index for age and address it may be more faster (but depends on source data).

Another advantage of using MySQL is caching data, so there is possibility that someone just has run the same query and MySQL can return exact data -- obviously it will increase performance.

Comment: yeah. Thanks bro. :)